# Timeout loading translations from YML file with I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, localization, rails-i18n, i18n-gem

I'm getting lots of these I18n::InvalidLocaleData errors when trying to load translation files on heroku:

```
I18n::InvalidLocaleData can not load translations from /app/config/locales/pt.yml: #<Timeout::Error: execution expired>
```

The files exist in our repo and pass YAML verification checks.  I haven't been able to find any reason for this timeout error.  Any ideas on a fix or workaround?

Some version info:

```
ruby-2.1.2
rails 3.2.21
i18n 0.6.11
```

Thanks!

---

**Update**

```
irb(main):001:0> YAML.load(File.open('config/locales/pt.yml'))
=> {"pt"=>{"meet"=>"Conheça", "he_is"=>"ele é", "she_is"=>"ela é", "years_old"=>"anos", "and"=>"e", "from"=>"de", "default"=>"Suas escolhas diárias estão prontas! Vejam antes que expirem em 24 has", "default_chosen"=>"Suas escolhas diárias estão prontas! Vejam antes que expirem em 24 has", "sunset"=>"We've missed you - check your Daily Picks today if you'd like to keep receiving them"}}
```

Comment: The Yaml format has versions (1.0-1.2). Check whether your validator is validating against the same version that your parser parses. I have found parsers (in the PHP world) that differ in what syntax they support and how tolerant they are of unquoted special characters

Comment: Post the output of `YAML.load(File.open('config/locales/pt.yml'))`

Comment: are you possibly exceeding the Heroku timeout of 30 seconds and this is just a red herring? Heroku will kill any request that last longer than 30 seconds and when it does so, you will sometimes get confusing errors like this.

Comment: that's definitely a possibility.  any ideas on how to confirm that / fix that?

Answer (score 0):

First it is not a `Timeout` error, it is `InvalidLocaleData`. It usually happens when `yaml` file is invalid. One of the most common reason is that people use `tabs` instead of `space` in `yaml`. I suggest you to check your `yaml` file with http://www.yamllint.com/ or something like that.

Comment: It actually is a timeout error. Scroll the error text and you'll see the `Timeout::Error` class printed